# How suppress "Open in app" banner in Safari on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari

When I view some photos at a web site in Safari on my iPhone 6 under iOS 11, I get a banner on top suggesting I open the photo in the Google Photos app (as you can see below):
[image]

For reasons not worth going into, I don't want to use the Google Photos app for this, I want to use Safari, but without the "Open in the Google Photos app" banner. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this: open `photos.google.com` in Safari, then pin the page to the iPhone home screen as follows:

- Touch the share icon (i.e., the box with the upward-pointing arrow).
- Touch the grey "Add to Home Screen" icon.
- Enter a label for the icon that will be added to the home screen.
- Touch "Add" or, on the keyboard, "Done".

When you invoke Safari via the icon for the pinned page, `photos.google.com` comes up full screen without the banner about the Google Photos app.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible for end users to hide the app banner if the website chooses to show it. If the website does not provide the ability to hide the banner then you cannot hide it after the fact.

If your device is jailbroken, you can install [NoAppBanners](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/8mf29r/release_nomorebanners_a_working_fix_for_the/) from https://repo.auxiliumdev.com/.